# Checking tab status in a chrome extension with a popup without the tabs permission

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, permissions, popup

I'm currently trying to build my first chrome extension and I only need it to interact with pages of a few domains, so I want to avoid using the "tabs" permission since I understand it would have me request access to all information and all domains.

Instead I want to restrict myself to using the aciveTab permission and, if need be, a content script.

In short, what I want to do is display a "Subscribe button" in my extension's popup if the currently selected tab's url is of the domain(s) I'm interested in.

I can get the url of the page when it's created using a content script but I don't know how to make sure the user is still on that page when my extension is clicked.

I haven't managed to get anything done with activeTab.

Thanks in advance for any piece of advice you can give, I'll check on the answers (if any) after work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example with the activeTab permisison:

In your popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({lastFocusedWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
  if (tabs && tabs[0] && tabs[0].url) {
    var match = tabs[0].url.match(/^[^:]+:\/\/([^\/]+)/);
    if (match) {
      var domain = match[1];
      if (domain == 'stackoverflow.com')
        alert('test');
    }
  }
});
```

Note:

1. You have to declare the "activeTab" permission in your manifest (of course).
2. JavaScript code must be in a standalone file and included in popup.html with `<script src="..."></script>`. Inline JavaScript is not allowed due to [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Comment: That worked perfectly. I spent an hour searching online, but could never get anything to work.